# How to remove isolated and get a clear non overlapping nodes of connected graph with networkx

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph

[image]

```
def gene_network_graph(self, edges, s, e):

        G = nx.MultiDiGraph(seed = 1)
        nodes = list(range(s,e))
        G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
        G.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)
        edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['weight'])
                 for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)])
        pos=nx.spring_layout(G,k=0.2)
        node_sizes = 400
        M = G.number_of_edges()
        edge_colors = range(2, M + 2)
        edge_alphas = [(5 + i) / (M + 4) for i in range(M)]
        nx.draw(G,pos, with_labels=True)
        nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)
        pl.show()
```

> I have total of 57 nodes. I need to remove isolated nodes and need a clear layout with non overlapping nodes. Also my edge weights are overlapping with each other.

Comment: Isolated nodes are the connected components that consist of a single node. You could use [connected_components](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components) to get the connected components and from that sellect the ones that have cardinality one.

Comment: I just saw that your graph is directed. It is, right? Those are little arrow heads. In that case you compute the connected components of the undirected graph. The latter you can obtain from [to_undirected](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.to_undirected.html).

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)